# Datetime is NULL when time format differs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

I have specific time scenario which can be 4 digit, 6 digit or can be NULL or string as mentioned below. Here in scenario 3 & 4 my method of calculating datetime is not working and coming as NULL
Is there any way to get date with 00:00:00:000 as time for case 3 & 4?
& for 1 it should be 10:02:00:000

```
DECLARE @DATE VARCHAR(10) =CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
DECLARE @Time1 VARCHAR(10) = '1002'
DECLARE @Time2 VARCHAR(10) = '160634'
DECLARE @Time3 VARCHAR(10) = '0900XX'
DECLARE @Time4 VARCHAR(10) = ''


SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, @DATE +' '
                                  +LEFT(ltrim(@Time1), 2) 
                                  + ':' + SUBSTRING(@Time1, 3, 2)
                                            + ':' + RIGHT(rtrim(@Time1), 2)) , TRY_CONVERT(TIME, @Time1), @Time1 AS Time

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, @DATE +' '
                                  +LEFT(ltrim(@Time2), 2) 
                                  + ':' + SUBSTRING(@Time2, 3, 2)
                                            + ':' + RIGHT(rtrim(@Time2), 2)) , TRY_CONVERT(TIME, @Time2), @Time2 AS Time

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, @DATE +' '
                                  +LEFT(ltrim(@Time3), 2) 
                                  + ':' + SUBSTRING(@Time3, 3, 2)
                                            + ':' + RIGHT(rtrim(@Time3), 2)) , TRY_CONVERT(TIME, @Time3), @Time3 AS Time

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, @DATE +' '
                                  +LEFT(ltrim(@Time4), 2) 
                                  + ':' + SUBSTRING(@Time4, 3, 2)
                                            + ':' + RIGHT(rtrim(@Time4), 2)) , TRY_CONVERT(TIME, @Time4), @Time4 AS Time
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you *really* need to fix your data model. What date and times do these values actually represent? What date and time does `160634` represent?  What about `0900XX`?

Comment: @Larnu 160634 is a 24 hour format & I am not sure how 0900XX came into database. I really can't fix the data model because it is coming from 1985 IBM main frame system on which I don't have access & my company have no interest spending time & money fixing that when we already in a stage to migrate data to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would, personally, "pad out" the values to be 6 digits, inject the `:` characters, and then use `TRY_CONVERT`. Then you use `ISNULL` to return midmight for failed converions:

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(time(0),STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + V.VarcharTime,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':')),'00:00:00')
FROM (VALUES(@Time1),
            (@Time2),
            (@Time3),
            (@Time4))V(VarcharTime);
```

If `1002` is meant to be `10:02:00` rather than `00:10:02` then pad on the right, rather than the left:

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(time(0),STUFF(STUFF(LEFT(V.VarcharTime+'000000',6),5,0,':'),3,0,':')),'00:00:00')
FROM (VALUES(@Time1),
            (@Time2),
            (@Time3),
            (@Time4))V(VarcharTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
..................
DECLARE @Time4 VARCHAR(10) = ''

select @Time1 = concat(cast(@Time1 as varchar(8)), replicate('0', 8));
select @Time2 = concat(cast(@Time2 as varchar(8)), replicate('0', 8));
select @Time3 = concat(cast(@Time3 as varchar(8)), replicate('0', 8));
select @Time4 = concat(cast(@Time4 as varchar(8)), replicate('0', 8));

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, @DATE +' '......................
```